# error while trying to create package.json file in windows 10

Tags: npm, package.json

Hi I have this error message as shown in the screen shot, this is while I am trying to create a `package.json` file. I am using a windows 10 OS

while i tried to create the `package.json` file, 
i click enter, in response to the question asked on the command prompt
the question is as shown below
Is this OK? (yes) I click enter, and the error that came up is as shown in the code

```
Is this OK? (yes) 
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Shad\Desktop\Computer School in Dominica\FULL STACK WEB DEV\git-test\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Shad\Desktop\Computer School in Dominica\FULL STACK WEB DEV\git-test\package.json'npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.npm ERR! enoent
```

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Shad\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-21T16_05_26_505Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Shad\Desktop\Computer School in Dominica\FULL STACK WEB DEV\git-test>
```

I am intending to create `package.json` file

Comment: hi welcome to SO. some advice: usually providing the exact command that you ran and that generated the error is helpful in finding the solution to your problem.

Comment: The spaces in the directory name man be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response, the problem still persists, is there a way i can send to you a screen shot of this challenge i have?

Comment: the command i used on the command line is npm init, then i followed the prompt and answered the questions that followed. but at the last line where i was asked;  Is this Ok? (yes) i typed yes and a very big error message was displayed. I can send the screen shot if any wishes to get it thanks

Comment: well as said above the problem is the spaces in the path name (side note as a general rule i NEVER use spaces in naming folders or files).. you can create the package.json file manuallyyourself, you do not need to do it via the prompt. but if you insist then yes please post more information, including screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful response. I was able to create package.json file yesterday, via the command prompt. I didnt not really do anything different, i just repeated the commands and again and to my amazement, the file was created. Its amazing though